# I have a program in C,here I keep getting error as ephem_read.h:No such file or directory though this header file is in the same directory

Tags: c

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ephem_read.h"
#ifndef TYPES_DEFINED

#include "ephem_types.h"
#include "ephem_util.h"
#endif
#include "state.h"
#define  PI 3.141592654

#include "ephem_read.cpp"
#include "ephem_util.cpp"
```

This the header part of the main code. The problem is as I told ephem_read.h:No such file or directory. Though the header file is written in same directory.

Comment: `C` or `C#` ?? Your title and body say `C`, yet you've tagged the question `C#` .....

Comment: sorry ,its in C.As I am new to C its difficult to sort out this error. I have gone through net but dint find appropriate solution.Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Not sure why it can't find the file.  I would carefully check the name (ex: since there is a corresponding cpp file, some people use .hpp for the header file.  Also, 1) You have 2 'cpp' files listed.  'cpp' files are typically C++ not C.  2) Including source files can be problematic.  Normally you compile them separately then link them.

Comment: What Operating System? What compiler or IDE?

Comment: Mine is windows 7 and I am using Dev C++. And gcc compiler